# How to know if a SIGHUP signal has been handled?

Tags: python-2.7, signals

I have a python script who sends a SIGHUP signal to another process, unrelated with my script (not a child, not alterable). When the process receives the SIGHUP, it starts a "light restart", reloading configuration file and updating information.
The "restart" doesn't stop the process, so I can't wait for an exit code. I know I can look at the process log file to know if the signal is handled, but that's too heavy and too slow for the script flow.

I would like to know if I can use another method to be warned that the SIGHUP have been received by my process?

Comment: By _reloading configuration file_, you mean just a read access? Because a solution would be to use the `lsof` Linux command to detect the access. I'm investigating how to implement this solution.

Comment: @DGeTuX that's true that my target process will read a configuration file. I didn't thought of that. This way can help me a lot indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) C library may solve your problem. Its installation gives you access to new commands: `inotifywait` and `inotifywatch`.

Let's say you have this */tmp/foo.bar* file. You can start watching for any read access on this file with the following command:

```
inotifywait --event access /tmp/foo.bar
```

Then, do a `cat /tmp/foo.bar` and the program will return.

As I said, it's a C library and I guess there are other language implementations of it. So feel free to not use this Bash example and write you own program using this library.

Comment: This solution seem to be implemented in python too with the `inotify` package. it's an "adapter to Linux kernel support for inotify directory-watching".
This method seem faster and less CPU intensive than parsing some log file where the line needed can be changed in a futur update of my target process. Thanks a lot, I will use this solution.